# Screen readers unable to read options of `vue-search-select`

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I inherited a vuejs project.  People using screen readers as assistive devices complain that  their screen readers are unable to read the options in drop down menus that were made from `vue-search-select`.  Here is how you can reproduce the issue:

1. Install a screen reader such as NVDA.
2. Turn on NVDA screen reader.
3. Go to https://vue-search-select.netlify.app/#/model
4. Tab to a search text field.
5. Confirm drop down of results appear.
6. Press the down arrow key to focus on any of the search result items.
7. Confirm the NVDA says the word "Blank" instead of actually reading out the contents of the selected item.

Here is a 10 second clip to that demonstrates steps 3 of 7.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nxx1k1oKETI

How do you modify `vue-search-select` such that in step 7, the screen reader will read out the contents of the selected item instead of reading out the word "Blank"?

Right now, as a temporary solution, I'm trying to write a `setTimeout` function that will automatically add the appropriate meta data to force screen readers to read out the content.  But I'm not sure how successful this approach will be.  I prefer an approach that is idiomatic to `vue-search-select`.

---

I tried adding a customAttr like so:

```
<model-select :custom-attr="ariaAttrs" />
function ariaAttrs() {
   return function() { return '" aria-label="hello" tabindex="0'; }
}
```

Although the attributes do appear in my developer console's inspector, my screen reader still does not read out the options.

Comment: Vue expects the attributes to be put on the element in the template

Comment: @DerekPollard - does `<model-select :custom-attr="ariaAttrs" />function ariaAttrs() {return function() { return '" aria-label="hello" tabindex="0'; }}` satisfy your definition of 'attributes to be put on the element in the template'?  If not, can you clarify? Thank you!

Comment: From what I can tell in the code, when you press the up and down arrow keys, the result items are NOT actually being `.focus()` by the the browser.  Instead, the `vue-search-select` simply adds or removes the css class `selected` from the corresponding`<div class="">` item.  Because the `div.selected` isn't actually being in `.focus()`, the screen reader naturally speaks the word "blank" to indicate you haven't actually focused anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `custom-attr` will not help you as it does not allow you to add any attr you want - anything the function returns [is just placed](https://github.com/moreta/vue-search-select/blob/2cb1c5addb68367fcca75eb5c209df6c89bae7fe/src/lib/ModelSelect.vue#L45) as a value of `data-vss-custom-attr` attribute

Any decent Vue library with similar functionality would offer a `slot` to customize rendering of menu items, but this [does not](https://github.com/moreta/vue-search-select/issues/108). Plus it doesn't seem to be maintained for a long time so maybe it is a time to look for an alternative....